# java database connection with OOP

Tags: java, eclipse

I create two separate classes in one package User and Login_window. I am using MySQL database

**Username:** Inventory_01
**Password:** g29egXRvFTGmYqf4

But my button ActionListener in Login_window gets 0 value because method call `userLogin` in user class returns 0 value why

```
//userLogin method in User class

    protected int userLogin(String user_name,String password)
    {
    try
    {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inventory_01","Inventory_01","g29egXRvFTGmYqf4");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    String sql = "Select * from user where User_name='"+user_name+"' and Password='"+password+"'";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                if(rs.next())
                {
                    a = a + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    a = 0;
                }
                con.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e) 
            {
                System.out.print(e);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.print(e);
            }
            return a;
        }

//class Login_window button actionlistener
JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
        btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
            {
                u.userLogin(txt_user_name.getText(), passwordField.getText());
                if(a == 1)
                {
                    Inventory_system i = new Inventory_system();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login done!");
                }
                else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Worng Password/Username !");
                }
            }
        });
        btnLogin.setBounds(12, 79, 97, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnLogin);
```

Comment: Looks like the user table does not have the data you are looking for

Comment: You may want to trim the Strings first.

Comment: Could you please take a look at your code style?   If you want people to read your code and help you, the onus is on you to write readable code.  At least get the indentation and line breaks correct.